# next_permutation returning strange results

Tags: c++, stl, permutation

Im trying to find ALL permutations for a given character list, in this case 'eta'

```
std::string s="eta";
do
{
    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;

}while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(),s.end()));
```

and I will get the following output:

```
eta
tae
tea
```

but if i change one thing

```
std::string s="eta";
```

to

```
std::string s="aet";
```

the output now becomes

```
aet
ate
eat
eta
tae
tea
```

which is the correct number of permutations i expect;
So there is clearly something different occuring when the 'scrambled' string is in alphabetical order?

or what could be the cause of this ambiguity?

Comment: add `std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());` after the first line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`next_permutation` changes the sequence to the next permutation in the sorted order of all permutations. Thus if you start from a permutation that is not the first in the lexicogrphical order, you will get only part of all permutations before next_permutation returns false.

Answer (score 3):

As the izomorphius pointed out, next permutation stops on *the last advancing permutation*. So if you want all of them, simply `sort` the character list.

Answer (score 1):

next_permutation rearranges the elements in the range [first, last) into the lexicographically next greater permutation of elements,

so there's nothing wrong with your output :)